# Influx - How to get time division data when data reset to 0

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I using Grafana and influxdb to collect ‘product data’ in the assembly line. I make a chat by grafana to show how many products was done in every hour.
[image]
It works good, but i have one problem, sometimes the worker will clear the total count because of shifts change. this cause the division data less than 0.
[image]

Considering this serial data(each data 10 minutes):

100 200 300 400 0 10 20

the correct time divisional value in this hour should be (400-100) + (20-0) = 320

I tried also search but no help, do you have any ideas? (Sperate to 2 time divisions when data set to 0 is also OK , in this sample, we can get two bars with 300 and 20)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use different approach with subqueries:

1.) Inner query will calculate diff between each record with `NON_NEGATIVE_DIFFERENCE()`
-> 100 100 100 0 10 10

2.) Outer query will just `SUM()` result of inner query and group it per hour -> 320